# Saving multiple blob records in mySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to export several emails stored in blob field in a table.

But it seems that DUMPFILE cannot process expressions or variables.

Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SearchAndExport;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAndExport(IN search VARCHAR(255), IN limitOutput INT)
BEGIN
    -- Handlers
    DECLARE eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    -- Outputs
    DECLARE emailId CHAR(36);
    DECLARE eml LONGBLOB;
    
    -- Cursor / Search Select
    DECLARE emails CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Id, RawContent
        FROM Email
        LIMIT limitOutput;
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eof = TRUE;

    OPEN emails;
    
    emailLoop: LOOP
        FETCH emails INTO emailId, eml;
        IF eof THEN 
            LEAVE emailLoop;
        END IF;
        SELECT eml
        INTO DUMPFILE CONCAT('/var/lib/mysql-files/',emailId,'.eml');
        
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE emails;

END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL SearchAndExport('mysearch',5);'
```

The error is

```
Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: DUMPFILE 0,0071 sec
```

If instead the expressión, I use directly a file name '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.eml' the code works (first record) and fail with next ones (reusing file name).